# Horror Movies, PTSD and The Mere-Exposure Effect

Tags: measurement, ptsd, trauma

Some people say that they get PTSD from horror movies, yet there are some researches done that claim that horror movies help fight against stress and even PTSD.

https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/how-horror-movies-can-help-overcome-trauma-and-relieve-stress

Horror movies may provide some durability against horrifying situations in real life with the help of "The Mere Exposure Effect" which desensitizes you or makes you get used to the horrifying feelings. However,

1)"Getting used to something" and "being desensitized" are not the same thing.
So, which one is occurring here? (My guess is both.) I think,

- Getting used to smth is when you know something, you see that its
  effects are there and ***do not*** care anymore.
- Being desensitized to smth is you ***can not*** care if you know
  it or it has any effects or not, simply you do not detect the
  thing.

2)What is the threshold between "getting PTSD" from a horror movie and "getting used to it" or "being desensitized" by it?

I think there have to be factors like age, culture, exposure rate, the density of exposure, etc. but the question is,

Are there any solid qualifiers/quantifiers that separate "getting PTSD" and "getting used to it" or "getting desensitized"?